# How to 301 redirect to new domain in a subfolder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I want to 301 redirect all pages from A.com to B.com. A.com is physically located in the "public_html" folder and B.com is physically located in the "public_html/blog" folder (a subfolder of public_html.

They are exactly the same sites, i.e., they have the same pages

I want to redirect ALL pages of A.com to the same pages on B.com but when I put this in the .htaccess file in the "public_html" folder, but it doesn't work:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^A.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.A.com$
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://B.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Verify whether your `.htaccess` is enabled or not, by putting same garbage (random) text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not?

Comment: Yes, that's definitely NOT the problem; my .htaccess is enabled

Comment: Are there more rules in this .htaccess, better you post your complete .htaccess